# Facebook not shows a thumbnails images when sharing a Drupal Site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal

It is the kind of problem when yesterday everything worked fine and today it's not. Nobody changed anything.
I have this website made with Drupal engine. When I am sharing an article on facebook, the title and the short text from it is visible, but there is no photo. 
Open Graphs are configured properly, as the developer debugger of FB is getting the meta tag with an image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite/page/tolia_74548279.jpg" />
```

When I am sharing a whole articles catalogue, images are there.
Do you have any idea where to start searching for a solution?
Maybe there is some fb servers problem I don't know about?

Comment: Give us a real example URL so that we can look at the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the facebook. It requires pictures at least 200x200px. Mine were smaller.